# Make faust.Record created from dataclass works with optional fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, faust

Currently i'am writting a python test so I can assure my `make_faust_record()` method works. This is how is looks like:

```
def test_order_supports_optional_fields_records():
    klass = make_faust_record(Order)
    payload = {"pos": {"hub": {"name": "Kitchen A"}}}
    instance = klass.from_data(payload)
    assert instance.pos.hub.name == "Kitchen A"
    assert instance.pos.brand is None
```

`Order` was generated using Google ProtocolBuffers, and as you can see, the first field is `id`:

[image]

This is the output i got from `make_faust_record`:

[image]

The problem is that when i call `.from_data()`, which is a `@classmethod` from `faust.Record`, it complains about the first field it which is not into the payload (`id`):

[image]

I wanna be able to run `.from_data()` against my `klass` (`faust.Record`), using a INCOMPLETE PAYLOAD and have as a result a `faust.Record` only contain the properties i provided in this INCOMPLETE PAYLOAD.

This is my `make_faust_record()` logic:

```
import abc
import inspect
from typing import Optional, Type

import betterproto
import faust

GENERATED_SUFFIX = "__FaustRecord_Auto"


def _import_relative_class(module: str, klass_name: str):
    resolved_import = __import__(module, fromlist=[klass_name])
    klass = getattr(resolved_import, klass_name)
    return klass


def _is_record(attype: Type):
    return (
        inspect.isclass(attype)
        and isinstance(attype, betterproto.Message)
        or isinstance(attype, abc.ABCMeta)
    )


def _build_record_annotations(klass: Type):
    annotations = {}
    for atname, attype in klass.__annotations__.items():
        final_attype = attype
        if _is_record(attype):
            final_attype = make_faust_record(attype)
        elif isinstance(attype, str):
            subklass = _import_relative_class(klass.__module__, attype)
            if _is_record(subklass):
                final_attype = make_faust_record(subklass)
            else:
                final_attype = str
        annotations[atname] = Optional[final_attype]

    return annotations


def make_faust_record(klass: Type):
    type_name = f"{klass.__name__}{GENERATED_SUFFIX}"
    record_type = type(type_name, (faust.Record, klass), {})
    record_type.__annotations__ = _build_record_annotations(klass)
    record_type._init_subclass()

    return record_type
```

Comment: Please include code and data as text, not as images. See [mre].

Comment: Ok i will edit, sorry!